# FullCalendar.Io shows header but doesn't fire eventsrequest on page load

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm using fullcalendar.io plugin. When I load the page with the calendar in it the header of the calendar shows up, but doesnt fetch/render the events. When I hit F5 or click a button in the header (<, >, today, week, month,...) then the events show up.

My fullcalendar function (note: it works in 2 pages other  where i use it)

```
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
        defaultDate: '<?PHP echo date("Y-m-d"); ?>',
        slotLabelFormat: 'HH:mm',
        timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
        editable: false,
        scrollTime: '08:30:00',
        eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
        eventClick: function(event) {
            if (event.url) {
                var vw = event.url.split('?');
                view(vw[0],vw[1]);
                return false;
            }
        },
        events: "views/personeelslid/weekrooster/events.php"
   });
```

Comment: If it is being shown/hidden in a tab interface (from below comments, bootstrap tabs?) you may need to call [$('#calendar').fullCalendar('render');](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/render/) when the tab is shown.